# keyup display total val of input and checked boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that works great for adding up the value of checked boxes. How can I add an actual input box to it that:

if you enter 100 into the input, it will add 100 to the #total

and still add in all the checked boxes when selected

working sample: [JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcyc5nf3/)

**html**

```
<form action="" id="products">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod1" value="10" />$10 product 1</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod2" value="20" />$20 product 2</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod3" value="30" />$30 product 3</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod3" value="30" />$30 product 3</label> 
</form>

<p>Total $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
    $('#products').on('change', function(){
        var total = 0;
        $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $('#total').text(total);
    });
});
```

I want to add in:

```
<input id="prod4" type="number" value="">

$( "#prod4" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val()*6.5;
    $( "p" ).text( value );
  })
  .keyup();
```

I would like the checkboxes and the input to use the .keyup function so that the #total automatically updates. Thanks for any help.

Comment: thanks Alexander - been a long day - did not mean to add in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it, hope it helps you !

```
<form action="" id="products">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod1" value="10" />$10 product 1</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod2" value="20" />$20 product 2</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod3" value="30" />$30 product 3</label>
<br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="prod3" value="30" />$30 product 3</label> 
<br />
<input id="prod4" type="number" value="" />
</form>
<p>Total $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

For the JQuery part :

```
$(function(){
function sum() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#products').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    var input = $('#prod4').val();

    if (input != "") {
        total += parseFloat(input);
    }

    $('#total').text(total);
}

$('#products').on('change', sum);
$('#prod4').keyup(sum);
});
```